# what are some disadvantages of having too many null values in one table?

Tags: ms-access

I am designing a database to store historical data for my company. Simply speaking, we want to store charges (fee) for products over the past ten years. The charges usually change once or twice a year and we want to store all the changes.

I have generated an idea based on the article from the following link:
https://jiripik.com/2017/02/04/optimal-database-architecture-super-fast-access-historical-currency-market-data-mysql/

I am thinking creating a table for every single product, with date as primary key. Then, I can prepopulates the table with null values from January 1, 2008 to December 31, 2018. So, I can simply update the charges instead of inserting new records.

This method is purely based on the article. However, the problem is that in the article, this method is used for historical currency rates, which changes way more often than my data. So, If I follow this method, I will have most null values in my table.

Can anyone tell me what are disadvantages of this method applied to my data? And is there any better way to design the database?

Note: There isn't a rule that how many times a product changes its fees in a year, and there isn't a constant date every year.

Comment: *"... creating a single table for every product, ..."** sounds like an horrible idea. Stop right there and don't even bother about NULL values.

Comment: And date as the primary key prepopulated is just asking to break for leap years.

Comment: hmm since there are still sub categories under each product, we will probably have 2400 tables in total in this case, is that too many for a database? [the ms access limitation on objects is 32,768]

Comment: Database design can be highly opinionated but the concept described in this article is complete nonsense and a maintenance nightmare. I would recommend to forget it and look into a properly normalized design.

Comment: store data with a date range (that doesn't overlap with another range for the given product)

Answer (score 2):

Many Null values aren't a problem per se, but that design is terrible.

You just need two tables,
**Products** (ID, Name) and
**History** (ID, ProductID, StartDate, Charge)

and if you want to query "what was the charge for product X on date Y?", you simply do

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 Charge
FROM History
WHERE ProductID = X 
  AND StartDate <= Y
ORDER BY StartDate DESC
```

getting you the last entry that predates date Y.

Comment: That does seem much easier! thanks!